# Why does "dbus: ...wpa_supplicant... getter failed" shows up on boot?

Tags: archlinux, dbus, wpa-supplicant, runit

This shows up after booting my x220 thinkpad:

`dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface.P2PDevice dbus_property=P2PDeviceConfig getter failed`

Btw, I'm using Artix Linux with Runit and also NetworkManager.